Use DS3231 with battery and vcc at the same time
I have ds3231 which i want to use to keep track of time even when the in my ase esp32 is without electricity. I however read some difference stuff regarding using the vcc and battery on he same time. Someone said it would destroy the battery. But
Using only battery will not be able to communicate with it (with i2c) since that only works with vcc
Using only vcc will not be able to keep track of time when power is cut.
Isnt the device switching between vcc when power is on and battery when it is off?

From the datasheet analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/… it seems that it you connect the 3.3v power supply and the backup battery (but not to the same pin), and when the power goes down, the battery is automatically used. It says that a " comparator circuit monitors the status of VCC to detect power failures, to provide a reset output, and to automatically switch to the backup supply when necessary. "

when I meassure over the battery pins I get 3.3volt over the battery pins when vcc is connected and no battery. isnt that supossed to be 0? It seems like i have go a charging unit in my module?

Your first stop on issues like this is the data sheet. Reading and understanding is a necessary skill for developers.

Isnt the device switching between vcc when power is on and battery when it is off?

The chapter "Power Control" has the table 1 on page 10:



SUPPLY CONDITION
ACTIVE SUPPLY




VCC < VPF, VCC < VBAT
VBAT


VCC < VPF, VCC > VBAT
VCC


VCC > VPF, VCC < VBAT
VCC


VCC > VPF, VCC > VBAT
VCC



Yes, it switches automatically according this table. BTW, VPF (power-fail voltage) is typically 2.575 V, see page 2.

when I meassure over the battery pins I get 3.3volt over the battery pins when vcc is connected and no battery. isnt that supossed to be 0? It seems like i have go a charging unit in my module?

The chapter "Pin Description" on page 9 tells us (emphasis by me):

VBAT Backup Power-Supply Input. When using the device with the VBAT input as the primary power source, this pin should be decoupled using a 0.1μF to 1.0μF low-leakage capacitor. When using the device with the VBAT input as the backup power source, the capacitor is not required. If VBAT is not used, connect to ground. The device is UL recognized to ensure against reverse charging when used with a primary lithium battery.

No, the battery will not be charged by the IC.
However, some modules with the DS3231 seem to include a charging circuit. Consult your module's documentation. And disable that circuit if you use a primary cell.
